# HTACCESS Redirect Subdomain with www and non-www to specific page on primary domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I know there have been quite a few posts on this but I'm struggling with how many variations there are with HTACCESS redirects and all of the ones I'm trying out here aren't doing what I was hoping, so maybe you can help me out!

**THE GOAL**

*www.shop.midwestsi.com*

and

*shop.midwestsi.com*

Redirects to:

*www.midwestsi.com/supplies/* (shop page)

Currently, the (non-www) redirects, but the (www) does not and goes to a page not found error.

Here's what I have in my HTACCESS file / What I've tried to no avail.

```js
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://www\.shop\.midwestsi\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.midwestsi\.com/supplies/$1 [L]
```

I also tried redirecting everything under that IP to the primary domain (because loading the home page is better than an error page), but this too had no effect.

```js
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^160\.153\.43\.65
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.midwestsi.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Tried this too, but I'm still getting no change:

```js
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop\.midwestsi\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.shop\.midwestsi\.com$
RewriteRule ^en\/home\/?(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.midwestsi\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for your help if you can see what I'm doing wrong here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?shop\.midwestsi\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ "https://www.midwestsi.com/supplies/$1" [R=301,QSA]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for your help with this! I appreciate it.